# How to make a button appear and disappear throughout a timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nstimer

I have this app which has a timer in it and I want to be able to display a button at random points in that timer. Sort Of like a game setting where you have to get the button to get more time before it disappears. I already have some code , but the problem is that the timer that i already have is being messed up ( i can tell because it is linked to a label. It messed up because it goes down by 2 instead of 1 and this only happens when i have the code to make the button appear  and disappear with the timer.

Here is the code to my timer that is being messed up:

```
-(IBAction)Ready:(id)sender {

    [self performSelector:@selector(TimerDelay) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    [self performSelector:@selector(randomTimer) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];


}

-(void)TimerDelay {

    MainInt = 36;

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(countDownDuration)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}
```

Here is the code to the button:

```
    -(IBAction)Ready:(id)sender { //the same ready action as above

        [self performSelector:@selector(TimerDelay) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
        [self performSelector:@selector(randomTimer) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];


    }

-(void)TimerDelay {

    MainInt = 36;

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(countDownDuration)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}

- (void)randomTimer {

    NSInteger randomTime = arc4random_uniform(0); //Some number between 0 and 9

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:randomTime
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(showButton)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:NO];
}


- (void)showButton {

    if(self.plus5.hidden == YES) {

        self.plus5.hidden = NO;
    }
    else {

        self.plus5.hidden = YES;
    }

    [self TimerDelay]; //Call random timer function again to run this method at a future random time
}
```

Comment: As an aside, method names should begin with a lower case letter, not a capital. Same thing for variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling "randomTimer" and "TimerDelay" (this should be "timerDelay") one after the other and scheduling and REscheduling "timer".

I think you should reconsider your architecture, here...

EDIT: Use just one timer and let it manage your button.

```
- (void)somewhereInYourCode
{
    shouldShowButton = YES;

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(timeFired)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timeFired
{
    // Here your countdown and...

    if (shouldShowButton) {
        NSInteger randomTimeInt = arc4random_uniform(9); // as suggested by Bergasms

        float randomTimeFloat = randomTimeInt;

        [self performSelector:@selector(showButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:randomTimeFloat];

        shouldShowButton = NO;
    }
}
```

This way your timer won't (probably) mess up.

Comment: What would you consider doing?

Comment: @KyleGreenlaw Take a look at my EDIT!!

Comment: Got this error " Implicit conversion of 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to 'UIButton *' is disallowed with ARC " on line stated above.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be releted to my code... shouldShowButton is a BOOL, but there is no code here where UIButton is called.

Comment: shouldShowButton, I connected this to a button. what should it be connected to?

Comment: You do not need to connect shouldShowButton to anything... it is a flag, a BOOL that just says if timeFired has to show your button or not. It can be YES or NO, if YES ("if (shouldShowButton)" in code) your button is shown, if NO it isn't. Just declare it this way "BOOL shouldShowButton;" in your .h file, where you declare other variables and use it casting YES "shouldShowButton = YES;" or NO "shouldShowButton = NO;" depending upon your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
    arc4random_uniform() will return a uniformly distributed random number
 less than upper_bound.
```

is one of your problems.

```
NSInteger randomTime = arc4random_uniform(0); //Some number between 0 and 9
```

needs to be

```
NSInteger randomTime = arc4random_uniform(9); //Some number between 0 and 9
```

I cannot say for the rest of your code. But the line you have will always return 0, which means the random timer will always execute instantly.

Comment: I did change it but it still messes up